# SQL JOIN and UNION

Tags: sql

can someone tell me what kind of join is this?

```
Select * from table1, table2
```

This query works like join and union at the same time but just want to check with others if this is considered to be an applicable query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an old way of writing a cross join. DO NOT USE IT.

Write it properly as:

```
Select * from table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

But, make sure you want a cross product of the tables. Cross joins are a fairly rare way to join tables.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!